# main.xml and strings.xml are overridden on android:generate-sources

Tags: android, maven, maven-3, android-maven-plugin

I've setup a clean android project using the archetypes. Whenever I try to modify main.xml and strings.xml in res/layout and res/values it fails.

To be more specific the editing fails doesn't fail, but after running `mvn android:generate-sources` or `mvn install` the files are replaced by the ones that are created by the archetype.

I'm using netbeans, but this shouldn't have any effect on the build-process.

Do I miss something or are these projects "readonly"?

Comment: I am using Eclipse, so can not help with NetBeans. But I can confirm that you definitely should be able to edit those file.

Comment: These files are definitely for editing. Please post any details about the error.

Comment: Editing these files works when being out of netbeans. When I change them within NB they're not saved! The contents are still the same as before editing in nb. After building netbeans refreshes the project and all the old content is back again.

Comment: It was easy... the generated-sources are the ones in target, so they'll be overridden all the times after a rebuild. I've added the /res folder as a resource to the maven project so they'll become classpath-elements as well and they can be edited successfully. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> It was easy... the generated-sources are the ones in target, so
>   they'll be overridden all the times after a rebuild. I've added the
>   /res folder as a resource to the maven project so they'll become
>   classpath-elements as well and they can be edited successfully. Now
>   everything works as expected. –  meme Sep 2 '11 at 15:36